# Jelix - Application Installation

Tags: php

I'm using the [Jelix PHP5 Framework](http://jelix.org) and when I try to install an application I meet this error :

```
php lib/jelix-scripts/jelix -portail installapp

Error: bad path in JELIX_APP_TEMP_PATH, it is equals to '/' !!
   Jelix cannot clear the content of the temp directory.
   Correct the path in JELIX_APP_TEMP_PATH or create the directory you
   indicated into JELIX_APP_TEMP_PATH.
```

My portail/application.init.php file contains :

```
<?php
/**
 * @licence  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU General Public Licence, see LICENCE file
 */
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/jelix/init.php');

define ('JELIX_APP_PATH', dirname (__FILE__).'/'); // don't change

define ('JELIX_APP_TEMP_PATH',    realpath(JELIX_APP_PATH.'../temp/portail/').'/');
define ('JELIX_APP_VAR_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/');
define ('JELIX_APP_LOG_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/log/');
define ('JELIX_APP_CONFIG_PATH',  JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/config/');
define ('JELIX_APP_WWW_PATH',     realpath(JELIX_APP_PATH.'../www/').'/');
define ('JELIX_APP_CMD_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'scripts/');
```

and my portail/application-cli.init.php file contains :

```
<?php
/**
 * @licence  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU General Public Licence, see LICENCE file
 */

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/jelix/init.php');

define ('JELIX_APP_PATH', dirname (__FILE__).'/'); // don't change

define ('JELIX_APP_TEMP_PATH',    realpath(JELIX_APP_PATH.'../temp/portail-cli/').'/');
define ('JELIX_APP_VAR_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/');
define ('JELIX_APP_LOG_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/log/');
define ('JELIX_APP_CONFIG_PATH',  JELIX_APP_PATH.'var/config/');
define ('JELIX_APP_WWW_PATH',     realpath(JELIX_APP_PATH.'../www/').'/');
define ('JELIX_APP_CMD_PATH',     JELIX_APP_PATH.'scripts/');
```

Do you know what's going wrong ?

edit : if someone can add "jelix" as tag ; thank you , because i cant do it until the reputation level is reached :)

Comment: [The Jelix support forum is here](http://jelix.org/forums/forum/4-jelix-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long time i've finished to find how to solve it.

in the dir temp there are directories

- portail
- portail-cli

but as we use a jelix script to manage the installation we have to create

- portail-scripts

then the installation will finished without any error

```
~/:$ php lib/jelix-scripts/jelix --portail installapp
~/:$
```

Hop this could help the next one ;)